Syncfusion Blazor pdf export no accented characters in header
I'm pretty new in using Syncfusion Blazor libraries and encountered a problem I cannot overcome.
I need to create pdf containing table with some data (sfgrid) and add a header on the first page with some metadata (like user who generated it, date generated, etc).
I encountered that some characters like ą, ę, ż, ź, etc was missing. I've started looking for solution and found this post.
I followed the instructions there and managed to make it working, but only for the grid elements in the header there are still none of this characters being printed.
I'm setting export options like that:
var exportProperties = new PdfExportProperties()
{
    FileName = $"myfile.pdf",
    Header = new PdfHeader()
            {
                FromTop = FromTopOffset,
                Height = this.Height,
                Contents = this.Contents,
            },
    IsRepeatHeader = false,
    Columns = columnsToExport,
    Theme = new PdfTheme()
    {
        Caption = new PdfThemeStyle()
        {
            Font = new PdfGridFont() { IsTrueType = true, FontSize = 12, FontFamily = InventoryReportResources.Base64EncodedFont },
            FontName = "Titillium",
            FontSize = 12,
            FontColor = "#000000",
        },
        Header = new PdfThemeStyle()
        {
            Font = new PdfGridFont() { IsTrueType = true, FontSize = 15, FontFamily = InventoryReportResources.Base64EncodedFont },
            FontName = "Titillium",
            FontSize = 15,
            FontColor = "#000000",
        },
        Record = new PdfThemeStyle()
        {
            Font = new PdfGridFont() { IsTrueType = true, FontSize = 12, FontFamily = Resources.Base64EncodedFont },
            FontName = "Titillium",
            FontSize = 12,
            FontColor = "#000000",
        },
    }
};
await grid.ExportToPdfAsync(exportProperties);

I'm sure this font supports all of the chars I want to be printed.
I'm adding text to header in this way:
List<PdfHeaderFooterContent> Contents { get; } = new List<PdfHeaderFooterContent>();
Contents.Add(new PdfHeaderFooterContent()
{
    Type = ContentType.Text,
    Value = text,
    Position = new PdfPosition()
    {
        X = x,
        Y = y,
    },
    Style = new PdfContentStyle()
    {
        TextBrushColor = "#000000",
        FontSize = 15
    }
});

For test I tried to print such string "aąbcćdeęfghijklłmnńoóprsśtuvwxyzźż" and got "abcdefghijklmnoóprstuvwxyz".
I've tried to set Font for the PdfHeaderFooterContent but always got "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."
According to the comments in code value can be either PdfStandardFont or TrueTypeFont.
I tried such approaches:

PdfStandardFont:

Font = new PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.TimesRoman, 12)


PdfTrueTypeFont

byte[] fontData = Convert.FromBase64String(Resources.Base64EncodedFont);
using (MemoryStream fontStream = new MemoryStream(fontData))
{
    var font = new PdfTrueTypeFont(fontStream, 12);
}

This is the full exception:
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.GridPdfExport1[<MyDataModel>].DrawText(PdfPageTemplateElement Element, PdfHeaderFooterContent Content)
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.GridPdfExport1[<MyDataModel>].DrawPageTemplate(PdfPageTemplateElement Element, PdfHeader Header, PdfFooter Footer)
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.GridPdfExport1[<MyDataModel>].InitializePdf(PdfDocument pdfDocument, String headerText)
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.GridPdfExport1.<ExecuteResult>d__178[<MyDataModel>].MoveNext()
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.GridPdfExport1.<PdfExportHelper>d__170[<MyDataModel>].MoveNext()
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.GridPdfExport1.<PdfExport>d__171[<MyDataModel>].MoveNext()
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.SfGrid1.<ExportToPdfAsync>d__117[<MyDataModel>].MoveNext()
   at <AnonymousNamespace>.ExportToPdf()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
2024-08-27T18:09:06.167+02:00  [ FTL ]  Specified cast is not valid. 
 System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.GridPdfExport1[<MyDataModel>].DrawText(PdfPageTemplateElement Element, PdfHeaderFooterContent Content)
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.GridPdfExport1[<MyDataModel>].DrawPageTemplate(PdfPageTemplateElement Element, PdfHeader Header, PdfFooter Footer)
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.GridPdfExport1[<MyDataModel>].InitializePdf(PdfDocument pdfDocument, String headerText)
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.GridPdfExport1.<ExecuteResult>d__178[<MyDataModel>].MoveNext()
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.GridPdfExport1.<PdfExportHelper>d__170[<MyDataModel>].MoveNext()
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.GridPdfExport1.<PdfExport>d__171[<MyDataModel>].MoveNext()
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.SfGrid1.<ExportToPdfAsync>d__117[<MyDataModel>].MoveNext()
   at <AnonymousNamespace>.ExportToPdf()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)

